# How create my calculate function for my example

Tags: odoo

I have two models a parent and the son contains two float fields
one of the values this calculates according to the other but when I change the father how can be my calculating function.
Here is my example:

```py
class A(models.model):
    trv_ids = fields.One2many(classB,id_A)

class B(models.model):
    id_A = fields.Many2one(classA)
    qtite = fields.float(default=0)
    qtite1 = fields.float(default=0,compute=?????)
```

`qtite1` gets the value of `qtite` when I change parent
as the example of cumulated amount becomes previous quantity the next month.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If i understood right i think what you need is something like this:

```py
 @api.depends('id_A')
 def _compute_qtie1(self):
     for record in self:
         record.qtite1 = record.qtite

 qtite1 = fields.float(compute=_compute_qtie1, store=True)
```

The depends is what triggers (any time you change the id_A field in the record) the compute method, if you dont store it in the DB it will re-calculate every time you open a view that contains the record.

Comment: thanks Mr dccdany for your help but that did not work like i want , he work in the same parent record, i want li khis exemple :  eng1  qtite1=0 qtite =30 next month eng1: qtite1=30 of qtite and qtite became 50 for example

Comment: How would be the use case to put qtite 50?

Comment: I enter it I enter it

Comment: If you had qtite = 30, and you change the id_A, the qtite1 should be 30, then you change the qtite to 50 and repeat process

Comment: but i want qtite1 of id_A1 beacme qtite of id_A2...(not in the same record that's the difficulty)

Comment: So you are not changing the id of the many2one but adding another record and want to get that value?, if all have the same parent you can just sort it and add the value based on the sort, maybe add a date to sort not by id